# Testing trigger account address insert

Tags: trigger, unit-test, account

I am new to salesforce and I am having trouble testing a trigger. When I try to write the address part of my trigger it does not accept it saying that string is being assigned to system.address.

Here is the trigger that I am trying to test.

```
  trigger copyaddress on Account_Contact__c (after update) {

    Map<Id,String> mapAccounts = new Map<Id, String>();
    Set<Id> setAccountIds = new Set<id>();

    List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>();

    for (Account_Contact__c t: trigger.new){

        setAccountIds.add(t.AccountContacts__c);
    }

    for (Account acc:[Select BillingStreet from Account Where Id in : setAccountIds]){
        mapAccounts.put(acc.Id,acc.BillingStreet);
    }

    for ( Account_Contact__c t: trigger.new){
        Contact c = new Contact(id = t.ContactAccount__c);
        c.Address__c = mapAccounts.get(t.AccountContacts__c);
        lstContact.add(c);
    }

    if(lstContact.size() > 0) {
        update lstContact;
    }


}
```

Here is the test class I was trying to create.

```
public void accounttest1() {

        Account a = new Account();
        a.billingAddress = '123 w fake';
        insert a;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is most likely with the unit test, not this code.

Comment: Your 3rd for loop is confusing me, what are you trying to do there?  I've never seen it written like that Contact c = new Contact(id = t.ContactAccount__c); can you try c.id = t.ContactAccount__c

Comment: Note that your test will have to update an Account_Contact__c as that is the signature of the trigger.

Comment: So will it be Account_Contact__c a = new Account()?

Answer (score 1):

BillingAddress is compound field and you can use it like this.
This field contains fields: BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry in it, so you need to change your code to:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.billingStreet = '123 w fake';
insert a;
```